# Force node to wait for a callback, or event listener on child process starting?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I have a test that requires loading up a an API locally via my make system. To do this, I'm using `child_process.exec`. Unfortunately, the callback on this only gets executed after the process dies, and I need the API up until the test is complete. I cannot figure out a way to get this to work.

```
request = require "request"
child_process = require "child_process"
tsc = require "training_service_connector"

campaign = "happy"
strategy = campaign
port_number = 54340
service_conf_filename = tsc.writeServiceConfig(strategy, port_number)
exec_callback = (error, stdout, stderr) -> console.log ('stdout:\n' + stdout + '\nstderr:\n' + stderr + "\nerror:\n" + error)
child_process.exec("CONFIG=#{service_conf_filename} make run_bidder_service_runner", exec_callback)
secret = {}
setToken = (error, response, body) -> secret.token = body.token
details = {"email" : "email@email.com", "password" : "password", "sendImmediately" : false}
request.post {uri: "http://127.0.0.1:#{port_number}/authenticate", json: details}, setToken
```

running this line-by-line in the REPL works correctly, but running it all at once produces an error.

```
opts = {uri: "http://127.0.0.1:#{port_number}/authenticate", json: details}
realtries = 0
val = 0
postAndCount = () -> console.log "#{realtries++}: {#{secret}}"; request.post(opts, setToken); clearInterval(val) if "token" of secret
val = setInterval(postAndCount, 2000)
console.log secret
```

This works (despite being a very circuitous way of doing things) and there is the further problem that the function this code is for will end up returning before the API is actually ready. Is there any way, whatsoever, of forcing JS to wait for some kind of trigger? Is there any library with a sleep() or wait() or any other way of making a function wait before returning something?

Re-engineering the whole testing system that this function is for with callbacks triggering every test is not feasible.

Comment: You've defined `secret`, but I don't see anywhere you're defining `this.secret`, which is the thing your code expects to be defined.

Comment: Just tried removing that and I still get the same error. I'll change it here to avoid confusion

Comment: Why do you think the error is coming from `secret.token`?  The error message says "cannot _read_ property", which means its coming from `body.token`.  Sounds like `body` isn't being passed as you're expecting.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. So the problem is probably that I'm getting an error because the API isn't up yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still unclear to me how to get around the problem :(

Comment: Have you checked `error`?  Does `make run_bidder_service_runner` do what you expect?  Is the `training_service_connector` module working?  There are too many unknowns to count, let alone list.  StackOverflow is not going to be able to help you solve a bug if you can't narrow it down to where the actual problem is.

Comment: I'm with @AaronDufour on this. You should at least post the output from `stdout` and `stderr` of the `child_process.exec`. By the way, if I had to guess, I would say that `tsc.writeServiceConfig()` is asynchronous, and the reason all this fails is because when you're running `make ...` the config file isn't yet created. This will explain why when running line-by-line in REPL it works (you type slower than the code runs, giving the config file a chance to get created before running `make`).

Comment: writeServiceConfig is synchronous. The problem is that booting up the API (the child_process call) takes a few seconds. See my edit for more details.